# Shell - Grep not working even though echo displays the variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, grep

Script -

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME=$(cat File1.csv)
grep $NAME File2.csv > Desiredoutput.csv
```

File1.csv

```
123
```

File2.csv

```
|123|abc|
|:-:|:-:|
|456|xyz|
```

Desiredoutput.csv

```
|123|abc|
```

Actual output - blank :(

Can you please help?

Comment: `NAME=$(unix2dos <File1.csv)`?

Comment: There may be nonprinting characters in the file (& variable). Run `set -x` to turn on tracing, and try again (then `set +x` to turn tracing off), and see if that indicates anything weird. Also, [`echo $var` is *not* a good way to see what a variable contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else).

Comment: line 2: unix2dos: command not found @Cyrus

Comment: @GordonDavisson tried "$NAME", still nothing

Comment: My first suggestion was wrong. It should have been called `dos2unix` but I assume that is not installed either. Try this: `NAME=$(tr -d '\r' <File1.csv)`

Comment: @Cyrus That worked, thank you. Do you know how I could input 123,456 in File1.csv and have the same code work. I dont want to go down the awk route?

Comment: I suggest to start a new question.

Comment: @LabeebNazim Read the answers to ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) first. Some deal with DOS/Windows line endings in the script file itself, but there are also some about dealing with line endings in data files (which I think is what you have).